# How to store data locally in Phonegap Android app (in AngularJS way)?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, local-storage

I am developing a Phonegap Android application using AngularJS. I came through a scenario where I need to store data locally.

After launching the app I want to store some data locally on click event of button and even If I kill the app or switch the app, I should be able to get that data.

I read about "Cookies" in AngularJS, localStorage, and sessionStorage, but not convinced which is better to use.

Which approach is better to fulfil my requirement or does some other way exist for Android applications?

Answer (score 0):

Try localStorage. It still stores data even after closing the app in the background.